# The creation of two html elements and appending one to the other does fail

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

I'm about to write a function that creates an image element that is enclosed by its as well created parent link element ...

```
function makeImage(source, link) {
  let hyperlink = document.createElement("a").setAttribute("href", link);
  let newImage = document.createElement("img");

  newImage.setAttribute("src", source);
  newImage = hyperlink.appendChild(newImage);

  return newImage;
}
```

Something is going wrong with the process of creating the "a" element. Every time `makeImage` gets invoked an error is thrown ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

This error is connected to the following line in my function code ...

```
newImage = hyperlink.appendChild(newImage);
```

Any hint towards the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: the return value of `... .setAttribute("...", "...")` is `undefined`, thus `hyperlink` does feature the latter value and of cause no method at all is available via `hyperlink`. Split element creation and attribute assignment into two separate parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDN documentation [MDN setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), setAttribute return `undefined`.

So I propose the solution below:

```
const hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
hyperlink.setAttribute("href", link);
...
newImage = hyperlink.appendChild(newImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute here:

```
document.createElement("a").setAttribute("href", link)
```

[Returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), not an Element. Try:

```
function makeImage(source, link) {
    let hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
    hyperlink.setAttribute("href", link);
    let newImage = document.createElement("IMG");
    newImage.setAttribute("src", source);
    newImage = hyperlink.appendChild(newImage);
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you S.LT for helping me figure out what was going on. Below is the code that ended up working for me. (There were additional problems not resolved by the other answers.)

```
function makeImage(source, link) {
            let hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
            hyperlink.href = link;
            let newImage = document.createElement("IMG");
            newImage.setAttribute("src", source);
            hyperlink.appendChild(newImage);
            return hyperlink;
}
```

Comment: The original poster (**OP**) does not need to repeat the code that others already have provided almost identically within an additional answer of her/himself, especially if it does not contribute to any new findings. But one always can use the opportunity of pasting comments beneath each answer. Also, anyone that is new to SO might now get familiar with how to ask question properly and how to format code in a better readable way.

Comment: nitpicking ... from a function that is named `makeImage` I do not expect to get a hyperlink (an `a`-element) as return value.